# GitLab CI ERROR: Preparation failed: Post https...docker%3Adind: net/http: timeout awaiting response headers

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

Error thrown by GitLab CI since past hour, Not able to proceed. `.gitlab-ci.yml` is not changed and very simple (*as shown in end*).

Only `Dockerfile` is changed - but system is not event launching `Dockerfile`. What is the remedy?

***ERROR LOG***

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.9.0 (82714ae)
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Post https://67.205.149.124:2376/v1.18/images/create?fromImage=docker%3Adind: net/http: timeout awaiting response headers
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Post https://67.205.141.137:2376/v1.18/images/create?fromImage=docker%3Adind: net/http: timeout awaiting response headers
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Post https://192.241.149.44:2376/v1.18/images/create?fromImage=docker%3Adind: net/http: timeout awaiting response headers
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Build failed (system failure): Post https://192.241.149.44:2376/v1.18/images/create?fromImage=docker%3Adind: net/http: timeout awaiting response headers
```

***.gitlab-ci.yml***

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build

variables:
  NAMEBRAN: registry.gitlab.com/myusername/project:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
  NAMELAST: registry.gitlab.com/myusername/project:latest

build_image:
    stage: build
    script:

#LOGIN     
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com

#BUILD [NEEDS PUSH TO NAME] WITH NAME = $NAMEBRAN
    - docker build -t $NAMEBRAN .
    - docker push $NAMEBRAN

#TAG $NAMEBRAN as $NAMELAST
    - docker pull $NAMEBRAN
    - docker tag $NAMEBRAN $NAMELAST
    - docker push $NAMELAST   

    only:
    - dockerbranch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started working without any modifications, Maybe internally gitlab server was overloaded hence timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

[67.205.149](https://db-ip.com/all/67.205.149) is a DigitalOcean IP address.
[DigitalOcean status](https://status.digitalocean.com/) is green, so it is not directly linked to the platform itself.
And this does not seem to be a [GitLab-CI `gitlab-workhorse` router issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/8-5-stable/doc/common_installation_problems/README.md#error-proxyroundtripper-xxx-failed-with-nethttp-timeout-awaiting-response-headers).

So check the state of the Docker registry hosted on that DigitalOcean instance used by GitLab: it (the docker registry) might be down (even though [GitLab Status](https://twitter.com/gitlabstatus) does not mention it).
The OP confirms it is the case.

Or use a [built-in GitLab Docker registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#using-the-gitlab-container-registry) of a private instance.

Comment: Am only using built-in gitlab docker image that is `image: docker:latest` in `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Also inside `Dockerfile` am using `FROM ubuntu:15.10` which is also not down as am able to built a different image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/sachingpta/dkr-ubuntu-15.10-x64/~/dockerfile/) which is based in `ubuntu: 15.10`. What could be the issue ?

Comment: ubuntu:15.10 comes from dockerHub: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/. But your other docker images seems to go through a private registry.

Comment: Not using anything private `image: docker:latest` is from github, `registry.gitlab.com` is from same repository at gitlab and my own login (*was working earlier*). Correctly said that `ubuntu:1510` is from [hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/)

Comment: Started working without any modifications, Maybe internally gitlab server was overloaded hence timeout error.

Comment: @SACHIN OK, so the server was down as I mentioned. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.